# Is there any way to make a menu link *not* a link?

Tags: routes

I have a hierarchy of links in my menu, but one of the higher level entries needs to simply be a category, and not link to anything.  It is "Related Sites" and has a bunch of related links under it, but should not itself link to anything.

Drupal doesn't let me save it without a URL, and vomits a bunch of errors if I try using '#'.

How can I achieve this with a minimum of hassle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the [Special menu items](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) module.

One of its features is:

> User can create a new menu item and place either `<nolink>` or `<separator>` to the Path field

Comment: It's kind of shocking this isn't possible with just Core.  It seems like such a basic need that would come up again and again.